# How would you fill this gap between a garage slab and a foundation wall?

Tags: concrete, cinderblock

This is in my garage so it doesn't have to be the most perfect solution, but I'd like to do *something* about this ugly gap between the cinderblock wall and concrete slab.

What would you use to fill this gap?

[image]

Comment: Decent looking and easy, wood(baseboard like) or metal flashing.  Ugly spray foam will do also.  A bit harder would be a 2x2 or 3x3 cement curb, or fill gap up with mortar.

Answer (score 1):

**Your desire**

Any solution you choose is going to bring even more attention to that seemingly small gap unless you paint everything after.

Overall, just get some mortar mix and fill it.

---

**Real problem**

Your floor is sinking. Any vanity solution will fail in 1-5 years.

Comment: Just jam some appropriately-sized backer rod in there.  If the gap continues to expand, replace with thicker rod in the future.